# Output from the node editor to the sequence editor

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor, video

I want to remove a green screen from a video. I know how to do it with the node editor but i can't send the result to the sequence editor. When i try with Add > Scene, it only show me the 3d scene(the default with a cube).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the VSE preview window press the <kbd>N</kbd> key to show the *Properties Panel*. Look for Scene Preview Render. Turn off *Open GL Preview*.

This should allow the compositor output to pass to the VSE.

If you had pressed the render button (<kbd>F12</kbd>), you would have seen the correct view.

EDIT:
Change the scene strip property > blend type to Alpha Over or Over Drop.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, i have the green removed and the video is in the VSE but, if I try to put a image in the background in the VSE, it don't work

Comment: Change the scene strip property > blend type to Alpha Over or Over Drop.